# Check if column exists and if it does check something about it

Tags: r, validation, if-statement

Hi I want to check if a column in a data.frame exists, and only if it does check another conditions.

I know I can use a nested if statement as I have in the example.

This is normally for checking inputs to functions. This is a working example which gives me the output I want, I just was wondering if there is a smarter way, as this can get messy especially if I am doing it for a number of conditions. My example:

```
testfun <- function(dat,...){
  library(dplyr)
  if("Site" %in% colnames(dat)){
    #for example check number of sites, this condition could be anything though
    if(n_distinct(dat$Site) >  1) stop ("Function must have site specific data")
  }
  #do stuff

  return(1)
}



testdf1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
testdf2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10,Site = "A")
testdf3 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10,Site = rep(c("A","B"),each = 5))


testfun(testdf1)
testfun(testdf2)
testfun(testdf3)
```

Edit with a bit more context: For this example the reason for this is that the user may input data that is site specific and therefore doesn't have a Site column (i.e. they have a data.frame with data only at one site so they have never specified the site as a column) or they might be using a data.frame that has had data for a number of sites specified in a column. So if there is no Site column it is safe to assume that data is for one site and the its valid to continue calculations, but if there is a site column I have to check that it only has one distinct value (eg might have been filtered on this column before applying the function of applied through `plyr::ddply`).
There are a lot of other cases however where I want to check that my input data to a function is of the expected form, and if the input is a data.frame this often means checking for column names and something about that column

Answer (score 0):

You can decide if this is a smarter way or not but one way is by separating the logic using `map_if`. Here we check the basic condition (`"Site" %in% colnames(dat)`) in predicate part and based on that we call two functions one for `TRUE` and other for `FALSE`. We still check similar conditions but by keeping the functions separate we can keep the code clean and it is easy to understand which part is doing what.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

testfun <- function(dat, ...) {
   unlist(map_if(list(dat), "Site" %in% colnames(dat), true_fun, .else = false_fun))
}

true_fun <- function(dat) {
    if(n_distinct(dat$Site) >  1) stop ("Function must have site specific data")
    return(1)
}

false_fun <- function(dat) { return(1) }


testfun(testdf1)
#[1] 1

testfun(testdf2)
#[1] 1

testfun(testdf3)
```

> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : Function must have site specific data

Comment: Hmm, I think this is interesting as it's not an approach I've ever considered but I don't think it will be practical for me as I may have a whole bunch of other things to check and therefore could get very confusing. So while I don't think it helps me this time particularly I think it might prove helpful in general in the future

Comment: @user2738526 sure, no issues. Actually it's difficult to optimise/improve/suggest an approach without getting the context of what exactly you are trying to do. It was just an attempt.